# ruby idioms for using command-line options

Tags: ruby, idioms

I'm trying to pick up ruby by porting a medium-sized (non-OO) perl program. One of my personal idioms is to set options like this:

```
use Getopt::Std;
our $opt_v;  # be verbose
getopts('v');
# and later ...
$opt_v && print "something interesting\n";
```

In perl, I kind of grit my teeth and let $opt_v be (effectively) a global.

In ruby,the more-or-less exact equivalent would be

```
require 'optparse'
    opts.on("-v", "--[no-]verbose", TrueClass, "Run verbosely") {
        |$opt_verbose|
    }
    opts.parse!
end
```

where $opt_verbose is a global that classes could access. Having classes know about global flags like that seems ... er ... wrong. What's the OO-idiomatic way of doing this?

- Let the main routine take care of all option-related stuff and have the classes just return things to it that it decides how to deal with?
- Have classes implement optional behaviour (e.g., know how to be verbose) and set a mode via an attr_writer sort of thing?

*updated:* Thanks for the answers suggesting optparse, but I should have been clearer that it's not *how* to process command-line options I'm asking about, but more the relationship between command-line options that effectively set a global program state and classes that should ideally be independent of that sort of thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A while back I ran across [this blog post](http://blog.toddwerth.com/entries/5) (by Todd Werth) which presented a rather lengthy skeleton for command-line scripts in Ruby. His skeleton uses a hybrid approach in which the application code is encapsulated in an application class which is instantiated, then executed by calling a "run" method on the application object. This allowed the options to be stored in a class-wide instance variable so that all methods in the application object can access them without exposing them to any other objects that might be used in the script.

I would lean toward using this technique, where the options are contained in one object and use either attr_writers or option parameters on method calls to pass relevant options to any additional objects. This way, any code contained in external classes can be isolated from the options themselves -- no need to worry about the naming of the variables in the main routine from within the `thingy` class if your options are set with a `thingy.verbose=true` attr_writer or `thingy.process(true)` call.

Comment: Note: Todd's URL structure seems to have changed slightly; it now lives [here](http://blog.toddwerth.com/entries/5).

Answer (score 2):

The [optparse](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/optparse/rdoc/index.html) library is part of the standard distribution, so you'll be able to use it without requiring any third party stuff.

I haven't used it personally, but [rails seems to use it extensively](http://github.com/rails/rails/search?q=optparse&choice=code) and [so does rspec](http://github.com/dchelimsky/rspec/tree/master/lib/spec/runner/option_parser.rb), which I guess is a pretty solid vote of confidence

[This example from rails' `script/console`](http://github.com/rails/rails/tree/master/railties/lib/commands/console.rb) seems to show how to use it pretty easily and nicely

Comment: outdated link for `script/console`, new link is https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/railties/lib/rails/commands/console.rb

Answer (score 1):

The [first hit](http://www.rubyinside.com/trollop-command-line-option-parser-for-ruby-944.html) on google for "[processing command line options in ruby](http://www.google.com/search?q=processing%20command%20line%20options%20in%20ruby&sourceid=mozilla2&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)" is an article about [Trollop](http://trollop.rubyforge.org/) which seems to be a good tool for this job.

Comment: I don't see how it's misogynistic.  They aren't calling anyone a name, they aren't making any judgements about anyone's promiscuity, etc.

Comment: One definition for the word is "A woman perceived as sexually disreputable or promiscuous."  That this word can, by definition, assign its disrepute only to the female gender, to my mind, indicates misogyny.  Given that, I see the application of the term to _anything_ as serving to propagate a misogynistic meme: the idea that there exist forms of disrepute that can only apply to women.

Comment: Note: I'm making no judgement at all about the software itself, I haven't looked at it closely enough to do so.  Just commenting on its name.